# Unable to sort Json Object based on values

Tags: javascript, json

I am sending one json object to browser and creating select drop down with key value pair. Now browser is automatically shorting the object based on the key which is messing up because my requirement is to keep it alphabetically. For example here is my `JSON` object

```
const inputObject = 
{
  108: 'C',
  109: 'C',
  111: 'O',
  114: 'O',
  115: 'R',
  116: 'G',
  117: 'H',
  118: 'R',
  119: 'R',
  120: 'R',
  121: 'R',
  122: 'R',
  2948: 'O'
};
```

I tried multiple solution nothing worked.

Here is one of the solution :

```js
       const inputObject = 
    {
      108: 'C',
      109: 'C',
      111: 'O',
      114: 'O',
      115: 'R',
      116: 'G',
      117: 'H',
      118: 'R',
      119: 'R',
      120: 'R',
      121: 'R',
      122: 'R',
      2948: 'O'
    };
    
    // Create an array of objects from the input object
    const entries = Object.entries(inputObject).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
    
    // Sort the array of objects by the 'value' property
    entries.sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
    
    // Create a new object from the sorted array
    const sortedObject = entries.reduce((acc, entry) => {
      acc[entry.key] = entry.value;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(sortedObject);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Expected output :

```
{
108: 'C', 
109: 'C', 
116: 'G', 
117: 'H', 
114: 'O', 
111: 'O', 
2948: 'O', 
115: 'R', 
118: 'R', 
119: 'R', 
120: 'R', 
121: 'R', 
122: 'R'
}
```

Comment: *"creating select drop down with key value pair"* - This is usually better done with an array, not an object.  Arrays can be more effectively sorted.  Alternatively, if for some reason you must use an object for this part, perhaps you can sort the options in the `<select>` after populating it.